# Xcode 10 fails to copy file generated by target dependency

Tags: xcode, xcode10

I have one target A that just runs a script and generates a bunch of files (localization files via twine). Other targets that copy these localization files have a target dependency on A so that they don't run before the files are generated.

Somehow, this doesn't work. Even though the files are all generated successfully, and I see that the copy files phases are running later, the files aren't found.

Also this only fails when I do a clean build. On the second build, the generated files already exist and the copies complete successfully.

For example, my script runs this:

```
bundle exec twine generate-all-localization-files Strings/ExtensionStrings.txt MyExtension/Resources --format apple --create-folders --tags ios
find /Users/me/proj/myapp -name Localizable.strings
```

I see it output `/Users/me/proj/myapp/MyExtension/Resources/zh-Hans.lproj/Localizable.strings` early on in the build process, then later on I see this:

```
builtin-copyStrings --validate --outputencoding binary --outdir /Users/me/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myapp-adfoisdfnasdao/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyExtension.appex/zh-Hans.lproj -- /Users/me/proj/myapp/MyExtension/Resources/zh-Hans.lproj/Localizable.strings

error: Build input file cannot be found: '/Users/me/proj/myapp/MyExtension/Resources/zh-Hans.lproj/Localizable.strings'
```

And again, if I build a second time it works. What the heck is going on? I'm guessing this has something to do with Xcode 10's parallel builds but I thought that putting the generation/copy in separate targets with a dependency between them would solve that problem.